# how do I cancel my Google Play subsctiption?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to cancel my Google Play subsctiption. I'm having problems accessing my account. I forgot my  password.

Comment: Can't you reset your password with your backup email or phone number?

Comment: https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel your Google Play subscriptions without access to your account. Follow the instructions here to recover your account: https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/

Requesting a chargeback for any transactions on your Google Play account from your credit card company could cause further complications, such as being charged additional fees and having your Google account restricted. So I don't recommend requesting a chargeback from your credit card company.